# Xcode does not save my keybindings

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Xcode always removes my KeyBindings after I reopen it.

I go to Preferences->Key Bindings and change "Delete Line" to "cmd+D".
As soon as I restart, the setting is gone. 
Maybe I'm missing something here but does anyone else have that problem?
And how can I workaround that?

Comment: Did you have a look to the defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the thing. Xcode gives You a hint if you bind a key
2 times. The problem is that the warning was not big enough for me to notice!

I resolved the conflicts and now everything works fine!